# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add url_launcher 6.0.3 in my existing flutter application and its showing Missing Plugin Exception, but its working with new project. Whats the issue here?

I did,

```
 flutter clean
 flutter pub get
 reopen project
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new dependency and you get this error, you should stop the app and run it again from cold. Hot restart will not work.

```
flutter clean
```

And reopen the project .It will definitely work .